# How can I correctly type the context object in Apollo Server?

Tags: typescript, apollo-server

I'm using [apollo server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/) with typescript and I'm having trouble getting the context parameter inside of my resolver to pick up that the `name` property on `context` is a string. Right now it's typed as `any` and I'd like it to be typed as `string`. I also see that the `context` parameter is of type any, when I'd like it to be a specific interface. Is there anyway to tell context and it's properties what type I want it to be rather than them all being typed as `any`?

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: gql`
    type Query {
      test: String
    }
  `,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      test(parent: any, args: any, context, info: any) {
        context.name // name is typed as "any" when I'd like it to be typed as "string"
      }
    }
  },
  context() {
    return { 
      name: 'John Doe' 
    }
  }
})
```

I tried to do something like this, but that's throwing an error.

```
context<{ name: string }>() {
  return { 
    name: 'John Doe' 
  }
}
```

I did get it to work by explicitly telling context what it needs to be, but this way seems a bit tedious as I have to import `Context` into every resolver file and cast manually.

```
interface Context {
  name: string
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
  ...
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      test(parent: any, args: any, context: Context, info: any) {
        context.name // name is typed as "string" here because I used "context: Context" explicitly
      }
    }
  }
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `resolvers` field on the `Config` object you're giving to `ApolloServer` is open to any types, but you can use TypeScript to do your own type narrowing.

For reference, `ApolloServer` accepts an instance of or array of `IResolvers` objects as declared here: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/a241d34e9275bf6a23cf7aa3ddee57f90de7b364/packages/apollo-server-core/src/types.ts#L90. `IResolvers` has generic type parameters, but those default to any: https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/blob/8c8d4fc09ddc63c306db16d7386865ac297794bd/packages/utils/src/Interfaces.ts#L298. In your code sample, `Query` is one of the specific types that make up `IResolvers` and `test()` implements `IFieldResolver`: https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/blob/8c8d4fc09ddc63c306db16d7386865ac297794bd/packages/utils/src/Interfaces.ts#L236.

You can take advantage of the fact that `IResolvers` has generic parameters to restrict the type of the `context` argument. For example, by explicitly specifying a type on the left side of an assignment, you can tell the compiler what to expect on the right:

```
interface Context {
  username: string
}

const myResolvers: IResolvers<any, Context> = {
  Query: {
    test: (parent, args, context) => {
      console.log(context.username) // based on generics TS knows context is supposed to be of type Context
    }
  }
}

new ApolloServer({
  ...
  resolvers: myResolvers,
  ...
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [graphql-code-generator](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator) to generate your types you can configure the context type in codegen.yml:

```yml
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.ts:
    config:
      contextType: "src/types#Context"
```

Then define your context type:

```ts
export interface Context {
  username: string;
}
```

Now the `context` argument of your resolver methods will be typed `Context` without having to import types or make any other changes.

Comment: When I initialized the code generator it created a typescript config file. How can I see set the context type with that file?